# If/else if statements not work with PHP form filter

Tags: php, forms, filter

I am trying to figure out why when I submit this form filter, my if/else if statements don't work. print_r($post); returns the correct filter value, however $printmain only shows 'rehab' no matter what filter option is chosen - which is strange because the $post variable is obviously changing. So I can't figure out why it's not going through the if/else if statements?

```
if(isset($_POST['filter'])) {

    $post = $_POST['filter'];

      print_r($post);

        if ($post = 'teamrehab') {$printmain = 'rehab';}
        else if ($post = 'heights') {$printmain = 'heights';}
        else if ($post  = '1225') {$printmain = '1225';}

    }

<html>
  <form method="post" id="filter" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <select name="filter" onchange="document.getElementById('filter').submit();">
    <option value="choose">Choose Client</option>
    <option value="teamrehab">teamrehab</option>
    <option value="heights">heights</option>
    <option value="1225">1225 Old Town</option>
    </select>
  </form>

<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){ echo $printmain;}
else echo "Please login with your Twitter account.";?>


</html>
```

Comment: your comparison operator `=` is assigning a value not comparing `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `=` instead of `==` in your if statements.

change the following:

```
if ($post = 'teamrehab') {$printmain = 'rehab';}
        else if ($post = 'heights') {$printmain = 'heights';}
        else if ($post  = '1225') {$printmain = '1225';}
```

to:

```
if ($post == 'teamrehab') {$printmain = 'rehab';}
        else if ($post == 'heights') {$printmain = 'heights';}
        else if ($post  == '1225') {$printmain = '1225';}
```

you need to know the difference between `=` which is an [assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and `==` which is a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)